# How can i fix routes of codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

**Something its not working, i have this in my routes.php file**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'books';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;


$route['cities']['get'] = 'cities/index';
$route['cities/(:num)']['get'] = 'cities/find/$1';
$route['cities']['post'] = 'cities/index';
$route['cities/(:num)']['put'] = 'cities/index/$1';
$route['cities/(:num)']['delete'] = 'cities/index/$1';
```

**and my .htaccess like this**

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

The problem here is that when i go to googleChrome and I type the url like this: ....www.domain.com.mx/project-server/

it send me to de default controller that it is books, or welcome, or wherever.
But when i want to type it on my url like this

...www.domain.com.mx/project-server/books
it appear an error like this:
The requested URL /project-server/cities was not found on this server.

this is my project in github
https://github.com/cmurra/project-server

Comment: The error - is it a codeigniter error or an apache error?

Comment: well i am really not shure, that is why i am asking XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your htaccess to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /<YOUR_ROOT_FOLDER>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$l [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 / index.php
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**

And to clarify, I think the problem is codeigniter is looking for the index.php

```
www.domain.com.mx/project-server/index.php/books
```

or

```
www.domain.com.mx/index.php/project-server/books
```

It's one of that

Comment: wow it is working. thanks. But in some tutorials they use www.domain.com.mx/project-server/books. Just like that

Comment: Can I get a check mark? Anyway, did you try my htaccess? I know what you're saying, my old projects used to run with index.php until i discovered that htaccess :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you might want to check the configuration 
`$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;` try setting it to FALSE (**Your URL domain.com.mx/project-server/books**) 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: I already did , but I don't have the route as i want :(
It still working with www.domain.com.mx/project-server/index.php/books. I Wish to have the route as you say domain.com.mx/project-server/books